# PC Won't sleep since 2 days ago

Tags: windows-10, sleep

My `powercfg` -requests shows this.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] Realtek High Definition Audio (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0900&SUBSYS_10438637&REV_1000\4&21453ba9&0&0001)
An audio stream is currently in use.
[PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe
Media Sharing has been enabled through Windows Media Player.
[DRIVER] USB Audio Device (USB\VID_1852&PID_7022&MI_01\7&39233eaf&0&0001)
An audio stream is currently in use.
[DRIVER] Legacy Kernel Caller

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
[PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
WebRTC has active PeerConnections

PERFBOOST:
None.

ACTIVELOCKSCREEN:
None.
```

I've tried to disable a few things and they have not worked.

```
powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE DRIVER "Realtek High Definition Audio" SYSTEM
powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE DRIVER "USB Audio Device" SYSTEM
powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE DRIVER "Legacy Kernel Caller" SYSTEM
```

My `powercfg -requestsoverride` looks like this.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> powercfg -requestsoverride
[SERVICE]

[PROCESS]

[DRIVER]
USB Audio Device SYSTEM
Legacy Kernel Caller SYSTEM
Realtek High Definition Audio SYSTEM
```

Things that have changed in the last few days is this.

I installed an equalizer for Spotify called Equalify Pro 1.1.7.
I added some headphones called JVC Real Sound System Z Series HA-SZ2000 and a headphone amp called FiiO E10K USB DAC and Headphone Amplifier which is USB.

I really haven't changed anything else besides this that I can recall. Any help would be appreciated. And again the problem is the PC won't enter sleep mode automatically but the power settings say it should turn off the display at 15 minutes and go to sleep at 20 minutes. As of writing this, it's been on all night. I've been using PowerShell instead of cmd prompt but it should be fine. First time really using PowerShell though.

Comment: Remove the things you added and see if it starts behaving properly again.  If so, then add them back one at a time until you find the culprit.

Comment: stop/disable the Media Sharing service via services.msc